# How do I change pages registering as 404 to 200

Tags: seo, google, html, 301-redirect

I have this problem. After relaunching my site: http://www.kgstiles.com, traffic dropped immensely(about 60%). After troubleshooting for a week and a half - losing thousands of dollars off of lost traffic in the process, I found that Google was getting a 404 error at the end of many of my 301 redirects(so it wouldn't index the new pages). Most of of the pages, though, would register in my browser. They registered as a 404 error in Google's index as well as a 404checker. So my first question is: could this be what's causing my loss of traffic? and second: how do I fix it?

I'm desperate! Any help is appreciated!

```
# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+
RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
    # END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/moreinfo$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/healthsolutions$1     [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301,L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing since you implemented 301 redirects you made some major update to your website. I see you are running WordPress now, did you run a different CMS before? If so one major factor in your traffic loss is the URL structure of your site changing. While 301's pass some link juice they don't pass all of it. The content changing on your pages also affects your rankings. So do you happen to know where your home page and other pages were ranking before you made these changes? If not you can go into Analytics under Traffic sources and compare date from before and after you switched platforms and determine which Traffic Source has caused the loss in traffic, i'm guessing it's organics but you'll find out for sure in Analytics. You can drill down under all sources, direct, referrals, organic etc to get a better picture of where you lost traffic.

Can you post a URL of the old website which is 301'ed to the new page so we can view the redirects headers please.

Thanks

Comment: Almost all of the traffic loss came from google. Even the other search engines are about what they were before, and yes we were using frontpage previously (an update was obviously long overdue). Sorry I didn't mean to enter that, I am writing more.

the url structure has changed and to counter that, we have set in the .htaccess file:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/moreinfo$1 [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/healthsolutions$1 [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301,L]
    

</IfModule>

Comment: which almost absolutely fixed the problems with redirect. One url redirect that illustrates what is happening is http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials.html redirects to http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/, yet when I check the server status of each of these urls, the first renders as a 301 redirect (as it should) and the second registers as a 404 error, but still renders fine in a browser. Apparently, though Google sees the 404 error and ignores the fact that there's content. So my question is how can I get google to see it as 200 instead of 404

Comment: I suppose that once that happens, I can resubmit my sitemap to google and the 301 redirects will transfer the link juice (or most of it as the content has not changed) and traffic should once again be where it used to be.

Comment: Yes resubmit your sitemaps to Google and Bing. If your 301's are working properly. Verify they are with any plugin to watch live http headers and just wait for Google to begin indexing your new pages.

Comment: My 301's are working fine. Even if they weren't, perfectly fine urls are resulting in 404's, but still rendering in a browser. The url I typed above (http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/) shows content when clicked on from a browser, but when I have google crawl it or 404check it with a third party site it is seen as a 404. I was told that if the page is a 404, google ignores the content. How can I get Google to see it as a 200?

Comment: Have you fetched one of these 404 pages as Google bot from Google Webmaster Tools to see what it returns?

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools itself takes a few days to update new sitemaps sometimes. So if fetch as Google bot comes back with a 404 just wait a few days. Because I see a correct 301, you may need to wait for Google to reindex it properly. I would also check what plugins you have enabled but doubt they are affecting the redirect and page.

Comment: you see a correct 301 when you click on http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/? That should be a 200. http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials.html is and should be a 301, but as far as I can tell http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/ is showing as 404 and not just in google.

Comment: The .html page redirects with a 301 to http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/ that works. But looking at the header of http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/ it also shows a 301. Maybe you have an infinite loop of 301's from http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/ to http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/ and Google is counting it as a 404 since it doesn't want to get stuck in an endless loop?

Comment: hmmm interesting..Where can you see that http://kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/ also shows 301? I'm using http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html and http://404checker.com/ which both tell me 404.

Comment: I will post my htaccess file in an edited response above. Is it possible that this is causing an endless 301 loop?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with rewrites but it's possible hopefully someone chimes in on here.